# How to find out style applied based on component props in material Ui v5 through browser dev tools?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, browser, material-ui

In Material UI v4 I can find out which styles is applied by component props classname through browser dev tools. This makes easier for me to be able to override the spesific styles of the component. But in Material UI v5 I Didnt know which classname styles is applied browser dev tools. How can I know applied classname styles, like .MuiButton-contained in Material UI v5 ?

Button variant="contained" in Material UI v4

[image: Button contained Material UI v4]

Button variant="contained" in Material UI V5

[image]

Answer (score 0):

All styles are applied to `.MuiButtonBase-root-Mui-Button-root`

> `@mui/styles` is the ***legacy*** styling solution for MUI. It is deprecated
> in v5. It depends on JSS as a styling solution, which is not used in
> the `@mui/material` anymore.

Use [the `sx` prop](https://mui.com/system/the-sx-prop/) instead.

Comment: I Mean,.. when we code <Button variant="contained">a</Button> i can know what styles is applied based on variant=contained  in .MuiButton-contained (MUI v4) but in MUIv5 how can i know that because in browser dev tools it didnt show the styles for classname .MuiButton-contained. sorry for my english.

Comment: All styles are applied to `.MuiButtonBase-root-Mui-Button-root`.

Comment: Yes,.. I think so too and which style is from .MuiButton-contained classname i don't know.

Comment: You don't need to know. You can simply use the `sx` prop.

Comment: "use the sx prop" is not a solution or an answer to the question.  What about using the theming mechanism, or one of the many other solutions.  The fact is that v5 took a giant step backwards in provide useful debugging in styling.  The OP is asking if there is a better way to do it.